# Existence of epi/mono factorization: a difficult diagram chase

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to show that in a regular category $ \mathcal C $ any morphism $ f\colon X\to Y $ have an epi/mono factorization. I can prove this fact easily in my own, apart from a single diagram chase that is making fun of me.

I'll rush to the problemaitc part of the proof. Let $ f\colon X\to Y $, take its kernel pair $ (p_1,p_2) $, and coequalize it as in
$$
X\times_Y X\rightrightarrows X\xrightarrow{c}C\text{.}
$$
Now there's obviously an arrow $ i\colon C\to Y $ such that $ f = ic $, since $ f $ coequalizes its kernel pair. At this point all that remains to be done is to show that $ i $ is a mono. We'll do that by showing that the kernel pair $ (q_1,q_2) $ is made of two equal arrows $ q_1 = q = q_2 $. Observe that there exists a unique arrow $ \phi $ from the pullback $ X\times_Y X $ to the pullback $ C\times_Y C $ such that
$$
cp_1 = q_1\phi\text{,}\qquad cp_2 = q_2\phi
$$
(draw the diagram). If we can show that $ \phi $ is an epi we are done, since $ c $ coequalizes $ p_1 $ and $ p_2 $.

At this point the resource where I'm studying this stuff from throws at me this big diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times Y X @>>> C\times_Y X @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV @VV{c}V\\
X\times_C C @>>> C\times_Y C @>>{q_2}> C\\
@VVV @VV{q_1}V @VV{i}V\\
X @>>{c}> C @>>{i}> Y
\end{CD}
$$
and states that $ \phi $ is an epi since it is the composite of two epis.

I know about the "two pullbacks" lemma and in some way I trust that what I need to know to prove what I want to prove is actually contained in that big diagram. Nevertheless I would like to see a more detailed explanation of this last step.

Comment: Use the lemma that you mention together with the fact that in a regular category, regular epimorphisms are preserved by pullbacks

Comment: Indeed I can build that diagram on my own using the lemma and I was already aware that thanks to the fact you mentioned the upper left square consists entirely of regular epis. Still I don't see why $ \phi $ can be obtained as the _composition_ of these.

Comment: Isn't $\phi$ the composition of $X\times_Y X \to X\times_Y C \to C \times_Y C$ ?

Comment: Yes it should be, but It is not so obvious to me from the way I've build up the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an annotated version of the diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times_Y X@>\alpha>>C\times_Y X @>\zeta>> X\\
@V\beta VV @VV\gamma V @VV{c}V\\
X\times_C C @>\delta>> C\times_Y C @>>{q_2}> C\\
@V\epsilon VV @VV{q_1}V @VV{i}V\\
X @>>{c}> C @>>{i}> Y
\end{CD}
$$

In this diagram there is a lot left implicit. Of course, the bottom right square is a pullback square by definition. The bottom left and top right squares are also *defined* (or "created") as pullbacks (well, you could define $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ from the pullback of $i$ and $ci$, justifying the notation $X\times_C C$, but this is equivalent by the pullback lemma). By axiom, since $c$ is obviously a regular epimorphism, both $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are (regular) epimorphisms.

The arrow $\phi:X\times_Y X\to C\times_Y C$ satisfies $q_1\phi=cp_1$ therefore $\langle p_1,\phi\rangle$ defines a unique arrow $\beta:X\times_Y X\to X\times_C C$ making $\epsilon\beta=p_1$ and $\delta\beta=\phi$. Similarly, $\langle\phi,p_2\rangle$ defines a unique arrow $\alpha:X\times_YX\to C\times_Y X$ such that $\zeta\alpha=p_2,\,\gamma\alpha=\phi=\delta\beta$.

In order to conclude $\phi=\delta\beta=\gamma\alpha$ is an epimorphism, knowing that $\delta,\gamma$ are regular epimorphisms means it suffices to show the top left corner is a pullback square since this would imply $\alpha,\beta$ are (regular) epimorphisms.

So, say, $u:Z\to X\times_C C$ and $v:Z\to C\times_Y X$ is such that $\gamma v=\delta u$. Using $f=ci$ and repeatedly moving through the commutative squares shows $f\circ\epsilon u=f\circ\zeta v$, so these induce a unique $w:Z\to X\times_Y X$ with $\epsilon\beta w=p_1w=\epsilon u$ and $\zeta\alpha w=p_2w=\zeta v$. This observation gives the uniqueness criterion of a pullback square so it remains to show $\beta w=u$ and $\alpha w=v$. Since $\beta w,u:Z\to X\times_C C$ are determined by their components on each factor of the fibred product (pullback) it suffices to show $\epsilon\circ\beta w=\epsilon\circ u$ (which we already know) and $\delta\circ\beta w=\delta\circ u$. $\delta\beta w=\phi w=\gamma\alpha w$ is an arrow $Z\to C\times_Y C$ and this is further determined by its components on each factor.

Observe $q_1\phi w=cp_1 w=c\epsilon u=q_1\delta u$ and $q_2\gamma\alpha w=c\zeta\alpha w=c\zeta v=q_2\gamma v=q_2\delta u$ thus $\delta\circ\beta w$ and $\delta\circ u$ have the same $q_1,q_2$-components and are equal; thus $\beta w,u$ have the same $\epsilon,\delta$-components and are equal.

A similar chase shows $\alpha w=v$ as desired. I guess this is like a $2$-dimensional pullback lemma, not one which I've ever seen before. The top left corner is then a pullback, hence $\alpha,\beta$ are regular epimorphisms and $\phi$ is a composite of epimorphisms hence an epimorphism itself.

Comment: Thank you! That first part where you built $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ was very helpful.

Comment: P.S. I've read your question about $ \infty $-categories in AT, and that other post in Academia.SE and I was wondering if you mind if I ask you a couple of things (I'm another frustrated self-taught student obsessing with topology, but currently in a culturally dead place)

Comment: @GeometriaDifferenziale Sure, though maybe this would be better in a private chatroom

Comment: I think I don't have enough privileges to open a private chatroom here. Can you? Otherwise I'll just drop here my email.

Comment: @GeometriaDifferenziale I made a chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148585/room-for-fshrike-and-geometriadifferenziale). Once I know you've seen this message I'll delete it. Anyone with $>20$ reputation can join/talk in a chatroom etc.